# vba for loop with data validation list

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I would like to perform data validation of a list through use of a loop, but I have an error 1004 thrown on this line:

```
 .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=lista" & i
```

this is the whole code:

```
Sub sampllle()
  For i = 2 To 6
  With Sheets("HSZI AD").Range("H972:H978").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=lista" & i
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem that i had to had some value in the cells that i wanted to convert into data validation lists. It works now

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back. Your code would appear to be applying validation five times but you are deleting it each time so that only the last will remain. Do you have named ranges "lista2" etc?

Comment: the .delete function wasnt suposed to be there you are right. I would like the cells h972-h978 to be data validation list where the formula is lista2,lista3 respectively which are existing named ranges

Comment: Do you mean that H972 has lista2, H973 has lista3 etc? In which case H978 will have lista8 which is beyond your loop?

Comment: yes it is, but the problem is with the addtpye row. If its beyond my loop, it still says the same error.

Comment: I've posted some code below but check your sheet is not protected and that the named ranges are definitely spelled correctly and exist!

Comment: It still doesnt work. Its the same error message 1004

Comment: Have you checked the things above? Is your sheet protected at all? Are all your named ranges a single column or row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub sampllle()

Dim i As Long

Sheets("HSZI AD").Range("H972:H978").Validation.Delete

For i = 2 To 6
    With Sheets("HSZI AD").Range("H972").Offset(i - 2).Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=lista" & i
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```